# Duplicated Gutenberg Block content using Advance Custom Fields to create Gutenberg blocks

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields Gutenberg Blocks.  I have a very simple block which just displays a heading, some text and a button.  I want to be able to place this block on the page multiple times and so have set to allow duplicate blocks on the page with the `SupportsMultiple: true`

I am using `get_field('heading')` to retrieve the value. This works perfectly for 1 block on 1 page.  But when I try two blocks the content is duplicated.   Block 2 title is overwritten by Block 1 title.  Block 2 is getting the data from BLock 1 instead of its own data.

Comment: This resolved itself.  The only change I made was actually deleting and remaking a different ACF block to sort out it's different glitch and somehow this one resolved itself.  Leaving this question up as I've come across it a few times with no answer.  Perhaps try and remake the ACF Block if you come across this issue yourself.

Comment: I am encountering this issue as well. Copying a block or blocks to another page, the content appears the same but when sent to graphQL API, the first block's data becomes the data for the second block.

Comment: It's been a while but has this issue been resolved? Currently stuck in a similar scenario :)

Comment: I'm sorry I never got a reply.  Has remaking the block helped you?